# Cannot Search for Site Pages on Managed Meta Data Column Referencing Term Set?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, sharepoint-search, managed-property, crawled-property

I have setup a Term Group (called "Company MetaData") and under this a Term Set (called "SharePoint Categories").  I'ved filed the Term Set with various Terms I hope to search on - for example "DevOps".

Following this I added a Column as "Managed Meta Data" to my Site Pages for my All Company Team Site in Sharepoint Online.  The Column name is called "Classification" and it is linked to the Term Set "SharePoint Categories".

I can now filter on my "Classification" column by selecting items from the Term Set "SharePoint Categories" when browsing the Site Pages.  So far, so good!

However my understanding is that I should be able to search (or query) by Column using the SharePoint Search-bar at the top of the page.  Whilst this works fine for text searches for the body of the pages in my site, I am unable to query for pages via the Managed Meta Data Classification column I've created.

My understanding is that I should be able to do:
Classification:DevOps

This should return any pages that have added the DevOps Term to their Classification colum, but I get zero hits.

I'm fairly new to SharePoint, and there's lots of advice online which doesn't quite explain my issue; the nearest I've come to an explanation seems to be the article I reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/how-do-site-columns-become-managed-properties-thus-available-for-search

The article explains using a text column rather than a managed meta data column, but seems to suggest that providing I'm explicitly a Site Collection Admin (I checked, I am), that SharePoint should work its magic and my new column should automatically become queryable/searchable without me doing anything?

Although 24 hours after adding the column I have cannot find my column in either the managed or crawled properties. [image: No Classification Crawled Property Exists]

It is not clear to me now if I need to add or rename a Managed Property, add a Crawled Property, or do something else to make this work?  Or if I've missed something in the setup I've done so far?

Could anyone help explain the right approach specifically for Managed Meta Data Columns?